# Obtaining n values from n-1 sensors

Tags: algorithms, statistics, classification, sensor

As the questions states, lets consider we have 3 gas sensors giving me data for:

- A
- B
- C

Note that only sensors for *A* and *B* give absolute values, yet we need the *absolute* values for all four species:

- A
- B
- C
- D

Where the sum of the four gases are 1: A + B + C + D = 100%.

Where should I start solving this problem from? How can the general case be described mathematically?

---

**EDIT:** As a real-world example, lets consider that:

- GSensorA: [O2 Sensor](http://www.alphasense.com/index.php/products/oxygen/)
- GSensorB: [CO2 Sensor](http://microcontrollershop.com/product_info.php?products_id=6782)
- GSensorC: [Pollution Sensor](http://www.sainsmart.com/sainsmart-mq135-sensor-air-quality-sensor-hazardous-gas-detection-module-arduino.html)
- GSensorD: Nitrogen via Signal Processing ;)

---

**Edit:**

My objective is to obtain *fairly* accurate air composition, based on the assumption that the air around us is composed only of oxygen, nitrogen, carbon dioxide and pollutants respectively. Therefore, if we know the volume composition of 3 of the above species, we will have the forth: which is where the title of this question comes from.

By absolute, I am referring to the fact that it is zero-referenced **and** is independent or other values. I'm sorry if this caused confusion.

Comment: Can you please edit your question for clarity? As it stands now, it is not exactly clear what you are asking. Also, is it possible to make it a bit more specific? What are sensors A,B,C and what exactly is the desired outcome that results as a sum of the A,B,C,D sensors?

Comment: We have three gas sensors named GSensorA, GSensorB and GSensorC which measure the amount of species A, B and C respectively. The sum of  species A, B, C and D is 100%. I'm looking a way to express this mathematically (neural networks?).

Comment: The absolute value of amount is amount, because an "amount" must be nonnegative. If it can be negative you must call it something else. Why don't you have access to |C|?

Comment: Thank you. If the sum of A,B,C,D is 100% and they are supposed to analyse the gas content **of a set volume**, then $A+B+C+D=100$ and so $A$ should account for $0.25$ of the total. Why neural networks? I am also seconding Olli Niemitalo's question. Can you please talk a little bit more about the application? I don't object to Neural Networks :) But at the same time, I struggle to understand the sort of difficulty that would call for their use in this case.

Comment: @OlliNiemitalo Only GSensorA and GSensorB give a absolute value (percentage of gas content in a set volume). GSensorC can only state if the gas content is more or less than a standard value.

Comment: @A_A _A_ is not necessarily 0.25. 



'Artificial neural network (ANN) based inverse modeling technique is used for sensor response linearization.'


Haugen, John-Erik, and Knut Kvaal. "Electronic nose and artificial neural network." Meat Science 49 (1998): S273-S286.
http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0019057807601384

Comment: Thank you. "Sensor linearisation" is not mentioned anywhere in the original question. I still believe it needs to be edited with all necessary information. What is the objective? Why should these outputs even be added? Does their sum provide the Nitrogen content? Is your final objective to derive Nitrogen content? Are you trying to understand if a specific gas is on the rise because of an underlying process that may be developing? Can we please clarify this?

Comment: Earlier you said that sensor C has a two-state output, but now in your example it has analog output. Which is it?